# How to convert DP, PX, SP among each other, especially DP and SP?

Tags: android, pixel, density-independent-pixel

I have known the difference among **DP**, **SP** and **PX**. And after searching this topic, I found nothing satisfying me completely. Maybe this post is a duplicate, but I still want to know what is the formula of converting from **DP** to **PX**, and **DP** to **SP**, from **SP** to **PX**, from **PX** to **SP**, from **SP** to **DP**, from **DP** to **SP**? I have known some codes to do this, but they are imperfect.

Comment: did you looked answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309354/formula-px-to-dp-dp-to-px-android

Comment: http://javapapers.com/android/difference-between-dp-dip-sp-px-in-mm-pt-in-android/

Comment: No, I think there is no satisfactory answer. They are imperfect. You said **This question was already answered for a thousand times**, then show me.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

**DP to PX:**

```java
public static int dpToPx(float dp, Context context) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

**SP to PX:**

```java
public static int spToPx(float sp, Context context) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

**DP to SP:**

```java
public static int dpToSp(float dp, Context context) {
    return (int) (dpToPx(dp, context) / context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
}
```

Comment: @Android777 Your former two code segment seem fresh. @DerGolem But why `dp = sp`, `device-independent pixel` is equal to `scaled-pixel`?

Comment: @SilentKnight Derived from this post (specifically from the image): http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025541/2649012

Comment: When a `TextView` is called `setScaleX` or `setScaleY`, both are equal too?

Comment: When  `android:scaleX = "integer"` or `android:scaleY = "integer"` are set of a `TextView`, both are equal too?

Comment: @DerGolem according to my knowledge, **sp** and **dp** can be different because sp takes into account user font size preferences as well. I believe that picture describes only one possible situation.

Comment: @DerGolem I wish I could find a solid example illustrating when they can be same and different, but I feel it's kind of a grey area. Many people (including me) know what dp and sp, and hypothetical differences between them, but some practical aspects are still in the dark.

Comment: @SilentKnight I noticed you amended your question. Do you want me to add other conversion directions you specified? Because I think it'll be some variation (inversion) of the existing ones, not too interesting.

Comment: @Android777. Well, they are `mostly` the same. As a rule of the thumb, always use `dp` for Views and `sp` for fonts. And you'll never fail. Sincerely, I've never investigated any further, since I follow this `golden rule`.

Comment: @DerGolem I totally agree, but then we come across a question about conversion between dp and sp, and we are not sure if this is a valid thing to consider...

Comment: Anyway... I rarely even consider converting px to dp and vice versa. Because I'm sure that Android does its best to scale my dps and sps correctly. Although there are occasions where I need to scale something which is given in pixels or pass a parameter to some method which expects pixels.

Comment: @AndroidEx You are correct.  SP can be different than DP based on user preferences for text size.  Conversion from sp to px or dp would be necessary for example in custom drawing where you want a graphic's size to correspond in some way to text drawn on a canvas.

Comment: sp one is wrong the correct one  public static int convertDpToSp(float dp, Context context) {
        return (int) (convertDpToPixels(dp, context) /  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    }

Comment: The difference between DP and SP is that SP is scaled based on the user's font size preference. You can't treat the two as being the same, it's totally wrong. That's why all text should be specified in SP and (almost) everything else in DP.

Comment: I was testing it and I have to use COMPLEX_UNIT_PX to get the real size in PX for SP. 

I don't know why but if use the COMPLEX_UNIT_SP I got a huge and not real text size.

Should be great if @AndroidEx can confirm us if this is correct or it is a bug in COMPLEX_UNIT_SP.

Comment: There can be valid reasons when to use dp for text though: Imagine having a text that serves (logically) as an image. E.g. one letter on a circle. Then you are not interested in scaling it up according to user preferences, cause it would scale out of the circle (defined in dp). You either have to define both in sp (if it's relatively small and should be sized up for accessibility) or both in dp (if it's that big, that no one could reasonably struggle to read it)

Answer (score 105):

The accepted answer is missing a few useful conversions.

### SP to PX

```
float sp = 20;
float px = sp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
```

or

```
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

### PX to SP

```
float px = 70;
float sp = px / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
```

### DP to PX

```
float dp = 20;
float px = dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

or

```
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

### PX to DP

```
float px = 70;
float dp = px / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

### Notes

- The floats I chose above (`20` and `70`) were arbitrary values. You can plug in different numbers if you like.
- `px` refers to pixels. The number of pixels that a device has per inch of screen space is called the density.
- `dp` means density-independent pixels. That is, no matter what device is used, the actual size should be the same. For example, if I set a view to be `100 dp` wide, it will have the same width on a new high density phone as it does on an old low density phone. (If I had set the width to `100 px`, on the other hand, it would appear large on a low density phone and small on a high density phone.) Density is measured in dots per inch (DPI). The formula is `px = dp * density`. So you just multiply or divide by the density to convert between `px` and `dp`.
- `sp` means scale-independant pixels. It is just used for fonts, not views. It is similar to `dp` except it also factors in the user preferences. This density with user preferences taken into account is known as scaled density. Setting a `TextView` font to a size of `30 sp`, for example, will make the text generally appear to be the same physical size on all devices. However, your grandmother may have her preferred font size maxed all the way up in her phone settings, so `30 sp` text will look bigger on her phone than it does on yours. The formula is `px = sp * scaledDensity`.
- [Meaning of DP and SP](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)
- DP to SP conversion is not generally useful

Comment: `scaledDensity` is now deprecated. Android 14 now does non-linear font scaling, so you should use `TypedValue.applyDimension`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 10):

For converting Dimension to Integer or Pixel you need to use "***getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.your_dp_value)***" function, Like...

Make a value in dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="padding_10">10dp</dimen>
```

Now for That value in pixel or integer you can use as like below:

```
int sizeInPixel = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_10);
```

Comment: Cleanest solution IMHO, without mentioning that splitting the file in values-* you can get different values for different densities, if needed...

Answer (score 6):

For `kotlin` I created an extension function:

```
fun Number.spToPx(context: Context) = TypedValue.applyDimension(
    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, this.toFloat(), context.resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
```

You can use it like `16.spToPx(context)` or `16.5.spToPx(context)`

*(I place such functions in a [`KotlinExtensions.kt`](https://gist.github.com/vedant1811/ec9ceb6ce2731281ad070255f52edb3a) file)*

Answer (score 2):

You can write a method, that doesn't need `context` or `resources`:

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}

public static int spToPx(int sp) {
    return (int) (sp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
}
```

By analogy, other quantities can be converted.

Comment: `Resources.getSystem()` is not configured for the current screen and cannot use dimension units according to the documentation

Answer (score 2):

According to [TypedValue#applyDimension](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue#applyDimension(int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)) source code and take advantage of Kotlin extension:

```
val Float.toSp get() = this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.scaledDensity
```

Other extensions from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54968591/2389923)

```
val Float.toPx get() = this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density

val Float.toDp get() = this / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density
```

Answer (score 0):

just inverting applyDimension() works for me, so this solution should work for all units.

```java
public static int unApplyDimension(int unit,float value){
    return (int)( b.getTextSize()/TypedValue.applyDimension(
        b.getTextSizeUnit(),1,
        getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
}
```

my formatting is atrocious, I know. Probably shouldn't have made it a oneliner. Oh well.

Tested & is working, but in a slightly different context where I had to animate the text size of a button, where the initial text size unit could be anything.