# Accurate conversion of dp to px in android programatically

Tags: android, pixel

```
public int dpToPx(int dp, Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17410076/6265154)

```
public int dpToPx(float dp, Context context) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, displayMetrics);
    return px; 
}
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665208/6265154)

What are the differences between these two?

Comment: I've edited the snippets to be more similar, so any comparing is easier. I've also removed the opinion based "which one is better" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the difference is in rounding value and truncating value.

Rounding of `4.6` will result in `5`
Truncating `4.6` will result in `4`.

It really does not relate to `Android`, and basically is Algebra, not a programming question.