# Text formatting in Textview

Tags: android, android-layout, formatting, textview, string-formatting

How will \t be treated while formatting a textview in Android. Would it be different from screen size to screen size?
Is there any alternative for it be similar in all screen sizes?

Comment: use [Constraintlayout](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1).

Comment: I meant in Textview.

Comment: use the `textsize` in `sp` instead of `dp`

Answer (score 1):

TextView size would vary from device to device based on the screen size and text size you give in your XML design. You can give `textSize` in `sp`

Example: `android:textSize="10sp"`

Based on the screen size, Android will convert `sp` size into `pixels`.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665208/5629056) SO Answer on how conversion works. You can read more about TextView from official document [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView).

Hope this helps.