# Convert sp to pixels programmatically on android

Tags: android, android-studio, pixel

I need to convert scalable pixels (sp) to pixels programmatically in Android. I already know how to convert dp to pixels, but how do I convert sp to pixels?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the Apply Dimen using TypeValue, like below.

```
public int spToPx(float sp, Context context) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, sp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

[It's an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665208/3502024), you may found a lot of discussion about this