# Convert Pixel to Dp for Custom Rounded Indication Clickable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to show a custom Indication when a button is clicked. The indication should be rounded in the corners and overlay a darker color. So far I was able to achieve this with the following code

```kotlin
Modifier.clickable(onClick = {}, indication = PressedIndication)
```

```kotlin
object PressedIndication : Indication {

    private object DefaultIndicationInstance : IndicationInstance {
        override fun ContentDrawScope.drawIndication(interactionState: InteractionState) {
            drawContent()
            if (interactionState.contains(Interaction.Pressed)) drawRoundRect(
                cornerRadius = CornerRadius(4f, 4f), //<-- How to use dp values?
                color = Color.Black.copy(
                    alpha = 0.3f
                ), size = size
            )

        }
    }

    override fun createInstance(): IndicationInstance {
        return DefaultIndicationInstance
    }
}
```

I can achieve rounded corners using `drawRoundRect` and `cornerRadius` but is there any way to use `dp` values?

*Note: I cannot use `clickable` and `clip` because the clickable area doesn't exactly match the indication area*

Comment: sounds like you're trying to do the same thing as the owl sample app's introduction screen from the [compose-samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples) repository. Maybe checking out the source code could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by [2jan222](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65736379/2016562) you can convert using `Dp.toPx()`.

In your case you could avoid to build a custom `Indication`.
You could use something like:

```
 val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
 Modifier.clickable(
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        indication = rememberRipple(
             radius = 4.dp,
             color=Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.3f))
        )
```

Comment: Can you also create squared ripples using this method

Comment: @Yannick Yes, you can, just set the radius to `0.dp`.

Comment: The question was about pixels to dp and not the other way around.

Comment: @Johann The question is *I want to show a custom Indication when a button is clicked.The indication should be rounded..*. The answer just explains how to do it.

Comment: The title says "Convert Pixel to Dp" - The title should be updated if that is not the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

May be late

```
val density : Density = LocalDensity.current
dpValue = with(density){ intValue.toDp() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Dp but you have to adjust to the screen's density. The extension function `Dp.toPx()` inside a density scoped code block works fine.

```kotlin
val sizeInPx = with(LocalDensity.current) { 16.dp.toPx() }
```

Comment: I have discovered you can also use `dp.toPx()` directly

Comment: Why the votes?? The question was about converting pixels to dp and not the other way around.

Comment: The function targeted only accepted px at the time I answered; thus this was the right answer. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108115/9957384 for density you can use ``LocalDensity.current``