# Android layout PX to SP

Tags: android-layout, type-conversion, android-edittext, pixel

I have been reading it is recommended to indicate `EditText` or `TextView` `textSize` attribute in **sp**. The thing is that my requirements indicate me 40**px**, but nothing regarding sp.

So, how can I convert these `px` in order to set `sp` into my layout?

Comment: it is already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664993/how-to-convert-dp-px-sp-among-each-other-especially-dp-and-sp

Comment: But I'd like to know it not at runtime time, because I want to set it in the styles/theme sheet